# How to compile rsync on MacOS and install it (not using brew)?

Tags: rsync

As sometime I am trying to compile a full version (with all options) of rsync on MacOS (please, do not ask why I want to do it - if you can help me clear and directly, thank you so much. Otherwise, do not waste your time).

I found **a really helpful script** made by "**junsionzhang**" (https://gist.github.com/junsionzhang), which in my option is simple and direct. Thank you **junsionzhang**!

Even being a good script, clear, step-by-step, there are some steps that does not work for me (and I tried a lot and for a while).

Here is the script (at Oct, 16, 2022):

---

```
#Compile rsync 3.0.7

#Follow these instructions in Terminal on both the client and server to download and compile rsync 3.0.7:

#Download and unarchive rsync and its patches
cd ~/Desktop
curl -O http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf rsync-3.1.2.tar.gz
rm rsync-3.1.2.tar.gz
curl -O http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-patches-3.1.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf rsync-patches-3.1.2.tar.gz
rm rsync-patches-3.1.2.tar.gz
cd rsync-3.1.2

#Apply patches relevant to preserving Mac OS X metadata
patch -p1 <patches/fileflags.diff
patch -p1 <patches/crtimes.diff
patch -p1 <patches/hfs-compression.diff

#Configure, make, install
./prepare-source
./configure
make
sudo make install

#Verify your installation
/usr/local/bin/rsync --version

#By default, rsync will be installed in /usr/local/bin. 
#If that isn't in your path, you will need to call your new version of rsync by its absolute path (/usr/local/bin/rsync).
```

---

The three patches lines does not work for me. After patching the fileflags, the rsync patched can not me "prepared", and of course, not be configured. The others, crtimes.diff and hfs-compression.diff, does not exist on the TAR package.

So, questions:

1. Trying to compile the 3.2.6 version os MacOS Big Sur (11.7), what do I need and which is the right/correct way and steps to patch, update and have the "correct"version?
2. How do I (correctly) compile and install the all the libraries to have a real full rsync version, with all features available (ACL support, Xattr support, xxhash, zstd, lz4, openssl crypto, and so on...)?
3. I would like to update and contribute to a new "junsionzhang" script version, making options to install a simple/standard version (rsync only) and options to install the libraries and choose for a "more complete" version, and help another Mac users and the community. How can I make this bash script?
4. How to install gawk, mawk, nawk, awk ( and where from (what are the differences): gawk, mawk, nawk?
5. Some libraries I already have installed (which I do not know if I did them right) seems to be outdated. How to I update them?
6. When running "./prepare-source", i get this: "make: Nothing to be done for `conf'.". Does this is right?

Thank you all! I really appreciate for all help I can get!

Comment: Are you able to use this script to compile version 3.0.7?

Comment: Guess yes, but as I wrote, I am using (and will) version 3.2.6. Anyway, the proposal is on having a script "versionless", so anyone can you no matter the version.

Answer (score 0):

**Completely untested (I don't run MacOS).**

URLs to access the source code:

- Source Version Tarballs: https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/
- Git repository: https://github.com/WayneD/rsync

might need these pre-requisites (from [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/blob/master/INSTALL.md)):

```
brew install automake
brew install xxhash
brew install zstd
brew install lz4
brew install openssl
```

code to download and extract (to `~/Desktop/rsync-3.2.6`):

```
# Download the relevant version of Rsync and the same version of
# Rsync patches, extract them and apply the "suggested"
# patches from the original script:

cd ~/Desktop

# Rsync
curl -O https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.2.6.tar.gz
tar -xzvf rsync-3.2.6.tar.gz
rm rsync-3.2.6.tar.gz

# Patches
curl -O https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-patches-3.2.6.tar.gz
tar -xzvf rsync-patches-3.2.6.tar.gz
rm rsync-patches-3.2.6.tar.gz
```

apply the "suggested" patches, light the blue touch paper and stand back:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rsync-3.2.6

# Apply patches relevant to preserving Mac OS X metadata
patch -p1 <patches/fileflags.diff
patch -p1 <patches/crtimes.diff
patch -p1 <patches/hfs-compression.diff

# Configure, make, install
./prepare-source
./configure
make
sudo make install

# Verify your installation
/usr/local/bin/rsync --version
```